Allowing different fundamental types to share the same memory location by using std::bit_cast instead of std::variant or union?
It's possible to store ints or floats in the same memory location using std::bit_cast (including ints larger than 2^24 i.e. they can't be stored as whole numbers in floats because the mantissa has too few bits). Example:
float storage = 0.0f;

//store a very large int using the underlying bits in a float:
storage = std::bit_cast<float>(2'147'483'647);

//retrieve the int:
int int_val = std::bit_cast<int>(storage);

//whenever you decide that you'd rather store a float than an int,
//you can simply overwrite the variable with whatever float value
//you want (analogous to an untagged / non-discriminated union)

I have a number of questions about this:

Does it rely on undefined behavior?
Could it fail on certain systems due to differences in floating point format, endianness or other reasons?
Could certain bit patterns be considered meaningless by a float and fail to be bit-casted or stored correctly?
Could this method be extended to sharing memory locations for other 4 byte types, or 8 byte types?
What are the advantages & disadvantages of this method compared to std::variant or union?


I suggest you to learn about the "union" types in C and C++. This is very likely what you are looking for.

@ivan.ukr I've used unions and variants, benchmarked them and considered pros and cons. This question is about comparing those against another method of achieving the same effect.

From the CppReference: "If there is no value of type To corresponding to the value representation produced, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple such values, which value is produced is unspecified.". Then, CppReference suggests it can be implemented just via memcpy().
So std::bit_cast() does not validate destination representation, it just copies bits. Copying bits should never fail itself, as long as source and destination are of the same size. However, if source bits does not represent valid destination type value, using it as destination type can cause UB sometimes. For example, if your int bits do not correspond to a valid float value, using arithmetic operation on that float is UB. But reading it, passing as parameter to another function is OK, because this is again, just copying memory contents.
In my opinion, std::bit_cast() is just a convenience function that allows you to write shorter and more clear code.
Compare the following:
Given
double a;

You can do the same thing with:
std::int64_t v = *reinterpret_cast<const std::int64_t*>(&a);

and
std::int64_t v = std::bit_cast<std::int64_t>(a);

But the latter one reads and writes better than the former one...

The latter one and the former one are not the same.  The former one std::int64_t v = *reinterpret_cast<const std::int64_t*>(&a); is undefined behavior since it violates the strict aliasing rule.
